# What is the basic difference between NAS, Hyperparameter Optimization/Tuning and Pruning?

Tags: neural-networks, hyperparameter-optimization

**As far as I understand:**

1. **NAS** = an algorithm that searches for the best NN architecture, i.e., how many layers, what activation function to use, how many neurons, etc.
2. **Hyperparameter Optim** = finding the best set of values for an already designed NN model.
3. **Pruning** = optimizing the connections between layers in a trained model.

**My question is,**

- When should I use which in the above?
- Can all three be used at a time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding question 1:

- Use **NAS** when you don't know which is the best NN architecture for your problem. Basically, you start from a set of pre-defined blocks and NAS finds the best way to connect them and also their hyper-parameters like number of blocks, filters, etc.
- As you said, **hyper-opt** is useful for an already designed NN (i.e. you know that such an architecture should work well) but also for the optimizer (e.g. learning rate, weight decay), and other hyper-parameters related to some custom layers, operation, loss. For example, in auto-encoders the size of the latent space is another hyper-parameter.
- Finally, **pruning** is a *model compression* technique. So you use that to remove a given % of connections in your *trained* model: basically it sets some weights to zero. Pruning is done to get a lightweight version of your initial model, with the aim of deploying it on mobile, low-power devices and even FPGAs (field programmable gate arrays) boards. The pruned model has to be compiled by specific tools in order to get a practical advantage of the weights set to zero, to reduce the number of operations and also memory usage.

About question 2:

- Well, I would use NAS first to determine the best NN architecture, then hyper-opt to find the best hyper-params of, e.g., the optimizer (and so not the ones related to the NN since NAS should have already found them), and finally, pruning as a post-training step but only if you want to deploy the model on some computing device with limited resources.